# FormatException when parsing decimals

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a code to do billing.  This is a small portion of my code:

```
private void NightsLabel_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

}

private void TotalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RoomChargeLabel.Text = (Convert.ToInt64(NightRateLabel.Text) + Convert.ToInt64(NightsLabel.Text)).ToString();
}
```

I am struggling when I hit the Total Button Click void.  Whenever I enter numbers that have decimals in them, it gives me an error:

> System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format".

Whenever I use whole numbers instead, it works just fine but I need to figure out why I can't do decimals.

Please help! :)

Comment: Int64 doesn‘t support floating point numbers

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Convert.ToInt64(NightRateLabel.Text)`, you should Use `Convert.ToDouble(NightRateLabel.Text)`

**Or you can do a twin transform check**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doubleVal = "123123";
        object fomattedValue = null;
        try {
            fomattedValue = Convert.ToInt64(doubleVal);
        } catch {
            fomattedValue = Convert.ToDouble(doubleVal);
        }

        Console.Write(fomattedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others pointed out, the reason you are getting an error is because parsing a long (`Int64`) doesn't support decimal numbers:

```
// Only supports whole numbers, throws an exception for decimal places!
(Convert.ToInt64(NightRateLabel.Text) + Convert.ToInt64(NightsLabel.Text)).ToString();
```

I'm guessing `NightRateLabel.Text` is actually a currency (money) value. In that case, you should use `decimal`:

```
var nightRate = decimal.Parse(NightRateLabel.Text)
```

You can also handle failures more gracefully by using `TryParse`:

```
// You can inline this (remove var success = ...) of course, but I'm being verbose to demonstrate:
var success = decimal.TryParse(NightRateLabel.Text, out var nightRate);
if (!success)
{
    // Handle parsing error gracefully: Show feedback to user, etc.
}
else
{
    // Do something with nightRate
}
```